# Magento 2 How to add custom slider on hyva theme

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, hyva

i am trying to build custom slider on hyvatheme i am only able to find one solution but instructions are not clear in this "https://docs.hyva.io/hyva-themes/view-utilities/custom-sliders.html"

[image]

Comment: You can use glider slider in hyva theme in phtml.